# Highcharts with DHTMLX menu appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, dhtmlx

I use dhtmlx menu on my charts. (legendItemClick event). It was working well when i use highcharts 3.0.1 . Today, I upgraded to 4.1.7 but dhtmlx menu's `legendMenu_<?=$id?>.showContextMenu(x,y)` function does not work like old one.

When i inspect the menu element on firebug, i see `display: "none"`. I tried to change it manually. However, Id is randomly generated.

```
legendMenu_<?=$id?> = new dhtmlXMenuObject();
legendMenu_<?=$id?>.renderAsContextMenu();
```

How can i fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.
`setAutoHideMode(false);`